# Replacing multiple items in rich text box

Tags: c#, string, richtextbox

I am trying to change multiple items in a richtextbox.
When I run my code the only item thats changed is the first

```
try
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                       richTextBox1.AppendText(reader.ReadLine());
                         richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
                    richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf.Replace(textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
                    richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf.Replace(textBox5.Text, textBox6.Text);

                    }

                }

               // using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
              //  {

              //  }
            }
```

Comment: please describe better. in the first append you are adding a new line of text in the end from the stream. After that your replace in all text value of tb1 with the one of tb2. does this also work? what about the others?

Answer (score 0):

I also think your way to loop in the StreamReader is not optimal, usually it's handle like this:

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
    {
        String line;
        // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
        // the file is reached.
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The file I am editing is a HTML document (Template), I need to change the template and save the answer into a different file. There are a few fields I need to change 1: first name 2: last name 3: parent name, these values apear more then once, The reason I am unable to o this dynamically is I would like to use dropbox to host the files, and dropbox does not support asp.net, php

Comment: ok but this has nothing to do with the problem. try to replace your stream reading with the snipped I gave you here, adapting to your case and let us know if it works :)

Comment: while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            line = line.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
                            line = line.Replace(textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
                            line = line.Replace(textBox5.Text, textBox6.Text);
                            Debug.WriteLine(line);
                        } still only changes the first variable

Comment: No matter what I do I only am able to change the first value and never the second